# How can I allow access to my database from another server

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a database called root, I want to create a user that can access the database from another server,
I have created external IP address if I need to it, and also allowed firewalls,
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a GRANT command for allowing other users to access your database.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'someip';
```

You can get more detail from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

WARNING:
When you allow access to someuser@someip allow only what access you need.

1. Instead of ALL you should use specific permissions (like select, insert whatever you need)
2. instead of on all databases and tables (*.*) specify the databases and tables that you need access to from remote server
3. you should not use root user

Comment: and the IP address: is that the other user's external IP address?

Comment: If I do this, how would I access the database from the other user account?

Comment: @user3051827 Yes. It is the external IP

Comment: @PeteR It is the first example from mysql grant page. After placing the link i added this as example. Now I will add warnings :)

Comment: @ZubaiR: Ah, that old trick. Get the first answer in to potentially gain rep and then fix it later.

Comment: @PeteR: Actually No. After I put on the link I thought since he is new to this a sample would help. Most of the time I am the last to comment :(

Comment: So guys, what is wrong with grant all and how do I login in other users account, as in do I just log in try to access this database?

Comment: It doesn't work When I try to login using mysql -h IPADDRESS -u linked -p root, it allwas me to enter password and then goes blank

Comment: you shouldn't put space after -p. >mysql -h IPADDRESS -ulinked -proot